# IE 9 border-radius doesn't work after mvc project is deployed to Win server 2008 r2

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, internet-explorer-9

When developing/debugging a plain old vanilla MVC 3 project in VS 2010 the border-radius style works fine (corners display rounded in ie 9).  However, after the project is deployed to IIS 7 on a windows 2008 R2 server the corners are no longer rounded in IE 9.  The corners are still rounded in firefox and chrome.  Any idea why?  I've tried to work around the problem with PIE.htc but the borders overrun a few pixels where they intersect - doesn't look great.
Thanks,
Jim

Comment: check if ; is still behind `border-radius: (int)px` `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ie dev tools to check the browser and document modes for the local and remote sites.

Is the server on your intranet? If so check the 'always use compatibility mode for intranet sites' setting.

Comment: Thanks!  The dev tools indicated that Document Mode was set to "Quirky".  I added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" > (per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx) and now the document mode is IE9 and the corners are back.